# SignalR client stops receiving messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My scenario is, that I have a form, that allows a user to upload a file. 
After this file is uploaded, it is processed, which generally takes ~40 seconds. Therefore I want to report the progress of the operation back to the user using SignalR. I do this by adding the connectionId as hidden element, so that it is submitted to the action method of my controller. In my action method I then hook up some event handlers and update the progress by getting the hubcontext and sending a message.

However the problem is, that after the first update, the client just doesn't receive any messages any more. I have verified, that the event handlers get called.

Code for my form:

```
 $(".selectForm").submit(function (event) {
      var progress = $.connection.progressHub;

     // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
                    progress.client.sendMessage = function (message) {
                        UpdateProgress(message);
                    };

     // establish the connection to the server
                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                        var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;

    //create hidden element for the connectionId, so that it is submitted with the form
                        var input = $("<input>")
                                .attr("type", "hidden")
                                .attr("name", "connectionId")
                                .attr("class", "connectionId")
                                .val(connectionId);
                        $form.append($(input));
                        $form.submit();
                    });



           function UpdateProgress(message) {
                     //display the progress
                            $("#currentAction")
                                .html(message);
                        }
    }
```

On the server:

```
          [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Save(string connectionId, MyModel model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    ...

                    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>(); 
                    hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).sendMessage("File has been received");
                    var processing = new Processing(connectionId);

                    processing.Step1 += OnStep1;
                    processing.Step2 += OnStep2;
                    processing.Step3 += OnStep3;

                    processing.Start();
                }
            }


           private void OnStep1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var identArgs = e as IdentArgs;
                if (identArgs != null)
                {
                    //this message is received by the client
                    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
                    hubContext.Clients.Client(identArgs.ConnectionId).sendMessage("Step1");
                }
            }


           private void OnStep2(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var identArgs = e as IdentArgs;
                if (identArgs != null)
                {
                    //but this message is not
                    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
                    hubContext.Clients.Client(identArgs.ConnectionId).sendMessage("Step2");
                }
            }
```

Turning on tracing on the server and the client produces the following output:

```
[17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'progresshub'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectio…au5Eet9Z9p&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 5333.333333333333 and a connection lost timeout of 8000.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking progresshub.SubscribeForProgress
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked progresshub.SubscribeForProgress
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:44 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'sendMessage' on hub 'ProgressHub'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:47 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'sendMessage' on hub 'ProgressHub'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:49 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:49 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting due to the server connection ending.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:51 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:51 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:51 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connect…C1%7CE%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=4'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:56 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:56 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:20:56 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connect…C1%7CE%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connect…C1%7CE%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=9'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:06 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:06 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:06 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connect…C1%7CE%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=1'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:11 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:11 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js:24 [17:21:11 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:58610/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connect…1%7CE%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'.

SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8 is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Dispose(). Closing all connections
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : End(9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : Cancel(9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (9395a49c-85c7-4a57-a194-b8d9e55a89c8)
```

I already read 
[this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) and [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting) already, but nothing stood out to me, that would explain this.

My questions are:

1. I am pretty new to SignalR and web development in general. Is there something that I am obviously doing incorrectly/suboptimal?
2. What else can I do, to narrow down the root cause?
3. Is there a simpler approach for doing this?

I would be grateful for any help your are able to provide.